# Where are the log4net Log files?

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a Windows form App which write to log files using log4net. The log file path in the app.config file is defined as:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs/LogFileName" />.
```

I have an msi setup project, which installs the above app. I install the App on the development machine, run the installed App, and as expected, it writes Log files under the directory, InstallDirectory/Logs/. The dev machine has a Win XP SP3 with all read write permissions.

But when I install the same on a testing machine, which has Windows 7 and I am not sure of the permissions, there is no "Logs" directory and no log files.

In both cases, InstallDirectory is C:\Program Files\Dir1\Dir2.

While I try to figure out where the files are, on the test machine by adding:

```
log4net.Appender.FileAppender rootAppender = (log4net.Appender.FileAppender)((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root.Appenders[0];
string filename = rootAppender.File;
MessageBox.Show(filename);
```

to the code, can someone please shed some light.

- Why could the files be missing?
- Does Win 7 has any different ways to deal with new files into the Windows installed drive?

Comment: Try to use something like: <file value="${LocalAppData}\YourAppName\Logs\LogFileName.log" />

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have said, don't run as admin to work around this issue.  Write to a folder/file that you have access to.

You can expand environment variables in your configuration to get special folders:

https://web.archive.org/web/20121226213809/http://www.l4ndash.com/Log4NetMailArchive/tabid/70/forumid/1/postid/16299/view/topic/Default.aspx

(or, as recommended in the deleted post on this question by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), an article that is a bit more generic: [Where Should I Write Program Data Instead of Program Files?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2008/02/05/where-should-i-write-program-data-instead-of-program-files.aspx))

Try:

```
${LocalAppData}/MyProgram/Logs/Filename
```

Or just:

```
${AppData}/MyProgram/Logs/Filename
```

As for which of these two to pick - I'm not sure what "roaming" is, so I don't know why you'd prefer `AppData` or `LocalAppData`. Probably worth a different question :)

Comment: ... and that works perfect! Cool. Thanks. Btw, what do mean: "(not sure what roaming is...)"

Comment: @Vishruth: I mean I have no idea why you'd choose `LocalAppData` or `AppData`.  The difference between them (if you check Jon Skeet's linked article) is that one is for the "roaming profile" and the other is for the "local profile".  I don't know what that means, or why you'd choose one over the other :)

Comment: Since he deleted his post, here's his link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2008/02/05/where-should-i-write-program-data-instead-of-program-files.aspx

Comment: Great.. Thanks for the link. Been a very helpful post today and a quick one too. Thank you all. As my StackOverFlow "Reputation" goes up, so does my liking towards SOF.. :) \nn/

Comment: The difference between `AppData` and `LocalAppData` is rather simple. In a Windows (AD) Domain – which you'd likely use at work – you can set up Roaming Profiles so that, should you move from one workstation to another, your personalized Windows and application settings migrate with you. Anything stored in the `AppData` folder is copied over the network, whereas `LocalAppData` will not migrate. Essentially, you would put user-specific files in `LocalAppData` which do not make sense to have duplicated over the network; such as large files or files specific to the system configuration.

Comment: Thanks man, `${LocalAppData}` is the key. I have seen other weird syntax like `{LocalAppData}` and `%env{LocalAppData}` none of which worked

Answer (score 6):

It's a permissions issue. In Windows 7 standard users cannot write to the `Program Files` directory. So if you are not running your application as administrator Log4Net cannot create this subdirectory. You will have to either grant write permissions to anyone to the `Logs/LogFileName` directory while installing the application or put the log file in the corresponding `c:\users\username\Application Data\AppName` folder.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows7, you are supposed to write to the `C:\Users\<CurrentUser>` folder. You may create the `installlog` folder here.