# log4net log file not being written when the app is deployed

Tags: wpf, log4net

I have a WPF app that uses log4net. When I run it in Visual Studio, the log file is created in the Debug or Release folder as expected.

However, when I create an installer and run the installed app, the log file is not created. I added the following lines to the code...

```
  string logFilePath = ((Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository())
                 .Root.Appenders.OfType<FileAppender>()
                 .FirstOrDefault()?.File;
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\log.log")) {
    sw.WriteLine("Log file: " + logFilePath);
  }
```

...to enable me to check that the log file was being written in the location I expected. It showed me that the log file was supposed to be written to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Physio Diary\PhysioDiaryClient.log` which is what I expected.

However, the file doesn't exist. Any idea why?

Here is the top of the App.config file...

```
<?xml version="1.0"
      encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
             type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender"
              type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File"
             value="PhysioDiaryClient.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-7level %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

The bottom of the file looks like this...

```
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"
                      sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>

</configuration>
```

The bits in between are all to do with the WCF services that the app uses.

Anyone any ideas?

**Edit:** As a test, I tried hard-coding the log file path in App.config to my D: drive (so it's hard-coded, and no question of a permissions issue), but the file still wasn't created.

Comment: You shouldn't configure the %ProgramFiles% directory to be the logging target, because generally speaking applications are not allowed to write to that directory.

Comment: @dymanoid Ideally, I'd like to write the log file to a customer folder in the user's Local folder. Any idea how I'd do that? Not sure that this is the answer though, as the file isn't written even if I hard-code the path to my D: drive where I definitely have permissions. Still it would be worth fixing the location first and see if that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @dymanoid for pointing me in the right direction. The log4net docs are a bit weak in this area, but I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8148117/706346) that pointed out that you can use normal environment variables in the config file.

With the aid of this [list of environment variables](http://www.rapidee.com/en/environment-variables), I ended up with the following...

```
  <param name="File"
         value="${LOCALAPPDATA}\Physio Diary\PhysioDiaryClient.log" />
```

This correctly write the file to `C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Physio Diary\PhysioDiaryClient.log`

Hope this helps someone.